# what's the lyrics in this line?

Tags: lyrics

What are the exacts words in this line of Aaron Tippin's song "Christmas is the warmest time of the year?

The time is:
1:36 - 1:39

Here's the song:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxZz1169s0Q

Are they:
"It's the sound of silence coming soon"?

Comment: the lyrics on the internet are incomplete and even the posted parts are incorrect so don't even bother to find it.

Comment: Looks like. Retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the verse you're referring to is:

> Hand in hand in Winterland
>   There's magic in the air
>   It's a sign that Santa's coming soon